# Application for managing daily routine

Tags: project-management, reminders, todo

Is there any good application that can manage a routine and remind me about every hour's task?

I am a very forgetful person. I literally forget every small task I have to do. So, I am thinking about an application which can do things like:

- Make a list for work on a **daily basis**
- Remind me of every hour's task
- Make a progress report (optional)

I tried some task manager, but I have to plan every single task by myself. It would be very helpful if the application can make a daily routine.

Comment: For which operating system? May it be a Web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Asana](https://asana.com/) (web based) is useful for daily/re-occurring tasks that need to be ticked off/completed:

[image]